# How to display values from subclasses in quasar q-table

Tags: vue.js, electron, quasar-framework

I am currently writing an quasar based electron app. In my typescript code i have the following interfaces:

```ts
interface CharterParty {
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
  cargoType: string;
}

interface PortOperations {
  expectedArrival: Date;
  actualArrival: Date;
  expectedDeparture: Date;
  actualDeparture: Date;
}

interface Ship {
  name: string;
  status: string;
  charterParty: CharterParty;
  loadPortOperations: PortOperations;
  dischargePortOperations: PortOperations;
}
```

I want to display data saved in a list ships:

```js
const ships = ref<Ship[]>([
])
```

in a q-table component. For that i defined the following columns to test it out:

```js
const columns = ref([
  {
    name: 'name',
    required: true,
    label: 'Name',
    field: 'name',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'status',
    label: 'Status',
    field: 'status',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'cargoType',
    label: 'Cargo Type',
    field: 'charterParty.cargoType',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'startDate',
    label: 'Start Date',
    field: 'charterParty.startDate',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'endDate',
    label: 'End Date',
    field: 'charterParty.endDate',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'expectedArrival',
    label: 'Expected Arrival',
    field: 'loadPortOperations.expectedArrival',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'actualArrival',
    label: 'Actual Arrival',
    field: 'loadPortOperations.actualArrival',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'expectedDeparture',
    label: 'Expected Departure',
    field: 'dischargePortOperations.expectedDeparture',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'actualDeparture',
    label: 'Actual Departure',
    field: 'dischargePortOperations.actualDeparture',
    sortable: true
  }
])
```

The q-table looks like this:

```html
<div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-table :rows="ships" :columns="columns" row-key="name" flat bordered />
</div>
```

Now my problem is that I don't get data displayed for the columns in the sub objects, CharterParty,DischargePortOperations and LoadPortOperations. Only the data in status and name gets displayed correctly.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't have much luck here, but in case someone else comes here, here is the answer that solved it for me from dongwa on github:

> You can try using the functional field.
> Example:

```
 const columns = ref([
 // ....,
  {
    name: 'actualDeparture',
    label: 'Actual Departure',
    field: (row)=>row.dischargePortOperations.actualDeparture,
    sortable: true
  }
])
```

Source: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/15810#discussioncomment-5859518